# Kettle's GUI variable scope vs "Modified Java Script Values" setVariable() scope

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm using the Modified Java Script Values step to call `setVariable(my_var, my_val, "r");` (`"r"` meaning "root" scope for the variable)

This works great except when my job calls another job which has parameters defined for it, where those parameters are of the same name specified in the `setVariable` var name.

### Ex:

- Primary Job Steps

  1. Transformation

     - Has step which calls `setVar("my_var", "2", "r");`
  2. Secondary Job (has parameter `my_var` which has a default value of "1")

     - Transformation

       - Reads value of `my_var` which is "1", not "2"

However, if I were to specify the value of `my_var` from within to GUI prior to running Primary Job, it will correctly be set to whatever I specify in the GUI.

Are the variables specified in the GUI assigned in a scope higher than "Root"? How do these variables carry through to my Secondary Job, but do not when assigning the variable through `setVariable()`?

Answer (score 0):

setVariable inside a Javascript step or using the Set Variables step work in the same way.

There's a more global scope, which is "Valid in the JVM", which is used when you define variables via the Edit/Edit Environment Variables menu options.

Comment: I'm aware of the Edit/Edit Environment Variables option. Is it possible that the variables defined within the "Run" dialog box are scoped with "Valid in the JVM" as well? These vars seem to work differently than the ones I set when I call `setVariable()`

Comment: I usually don't set the variables on the Run window; but it could be that they're defined to be valid in the JVM, yes.